# Confusion about basic reference distance based path loss formula in wireless communication

Tags: wireless

In the following, I am confused about results I am getting by the reference distance based pathloss formula.
My transmitter power is 1 mW (i.e. -30 dB). But the received power is much much higher than that (starts from 200 dB). I have used the textbook formula (PL = Pathloss, do, Po = reference distance and reference power, d = actual power, alpha = pathloss component)

> PL = 10 xalpha x 10 x log10(d/do) -PL0

. However, I am not sure what is wrong with it. The Matlab code and the images are below.

```
Pt = 1e-3; %(1mW)
do = 1; % (meter) Reference distance
alpha = 2; % Pathloss exponent
PL0 = 30; % (dB) Reference pathloss at distance do

PL(idx) = 10*alpha*log10(d/do) - PL0;;
```

[image: Pathloss and received power from the reference distance model]

Comment: Try Po=-30dBm an plot x on a log scale, your code is wrong

Comment: Pathloss should not be a negative value because it makes it path-gain and that's plain silly (as we all know).

Comment: Friis Loss calculations are for far field only. Try again